# linq2sql - How to use raw SQL to get a count from DB?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Currently, for a getting a count of items in a complicated query with joins i am doing something like this --

```
string q = @"SELECT f.FILE_ID
           FROM [Email.Link] AS l INNER JOIN Email AS e ON (l.EMAIL_ID = e.EMAIL_ID)
           INNER JOIN File AS f ON (e.EMAIL_ID = f.EMAIL_ID)
           WHERE l.EntityId = 123";

var files = Context.ExecuteQuery<File>(q);
return files.Count();
```

any better way to do this, rather than getting all the ID's back and counting?
I would prefer to do a `SELECT Count(*)` and get the int back in linq.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a LINQ query?

Comment: we were using before linq queries before .. but it got really complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    string q = @"SELECT COUNT(f.FILE_ID)
    FROM [Email.Link] AS l INNER JOIN Email AS e ON (l.EMAIL_ID = e.EMAIL_ID)
    INNER JOIN File AS f ON (e.EMAIL_ID = f.EMAIL_ID)
    WHERE l.EntityId = 123";

   return Context.ExecuteQuery<Int32>(q).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The executeQuery was actually returning Ienumerable<int> .. But doing .FirstOrDefault() on it gives me the correct answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `FILE_ID` collection you can return the ready `COUNT` as a part of your SQL query:

```
        string q = @"SELECT COUNT(f.FILE_ID)
        FROM [Email.Link] AS l INNER JOIN Email AS e ON (l.EMAIL_ID = e.EMAIL_ID)
        INNER JOIN File AS f ON (e.EMAIL_ID = f.EMAIL_ID)
        WHERE l.EntityId = 123";

       return Context.ExecuteQuery<Int32>(q);
```